# MXNet classification in Python always gives the same predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, mxnet

What I am trying here is, by using the Tennis Match Statistics Data Set provided [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Tennis+Major+Tournament+Match+Statistics) as an input, I made a neural network model that predicts the match results (1 or 0).

By following the official mxnet documents, I developed a program below.
I tried with various configuration parameters such as batch_size, unit_size, act_type,learning_rate, but no matter what kind I of modifications that I could think of, the accuracy I got was always been around 0.5 and always predicted either all 1 or 0.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import mxnet as mx
import logging
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)-15s %(message)s')

batch_size = 100
train_data = np.loadtxt("dm.csv",delimiter=",")
train_data = normalize(train_data, norm='l1', axis=0)
train_lbl = np.loadtxt("dm_lbl.csv",delimiter=",")
eval_data = np.loadtxt("dw.csv",delimiter=",")
eval_data = normalize(eval_data, norm='l1', axis=0)
eval_lbl = np.loadtxt("dw_lbl.csv",delimiter=",")


train_iter = mx.io.NDArrayIter(train_data, train_lbl, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_iter = mx.io.NDArrayIter(eval_data, eval_lbl, batch_size=batch_size)


data = mx.sym.var('data')
# The first fully-connected layer and the corresponding activation function
fc1  = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=data, num_hidden=220)
#bn1 = mx.sym.BatchNorm(data = fc1, name="bn1")
act1 = mx.sym.Activation(data=fc1, act_type="sigmoid")

# The second fully-connected layer and the corresponding activation function
fc2  = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=act1, num_hidden = 220)
#bn2 = mx.sym.BatchNorm(data = fc2, name="bn2")
act2 = mx.sym.Activation(data=fc2, act_type="sigmoid")

# The third fully-connected layer and the corresponding activation function
fc3  = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=act2, num_hidden = 110)
#bn3 = mx.sym.BatchNorm(data = fc3, name="bn3")
act3 = mx.sym.Activation(data=fc3, act_type="sigmoid")

# output class(es)
fc4  = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=act3, num_hidden=2)
# Softmax with cross entropy loss
mlp  = mx.sym.SoftmaxOutput(data=fc4, name='softmax')

mod = mx.mod.Module(symbol=mlp,
                    context=mx.cpu(),
                    data_names=['data'],
                    label_names=['softmax_label'])
mod.fit(train_iter,
        eval_data=val_iter,
        optimizer='sgd',
        optimizer_params={'learning_rate':0.03},
        eval_metric='rmse',
        num_epoch=10,
        batch_end_callback = mx.callback.Speedometer(batch_size, 100)) # output progress for each 200 data batches)

prob = mod.predict(val_iter).asnumpy()
#print(prob)

for unit in prob:
    print 'Classified as %d with probability %f' % (unit.argmax(), max(unit))
```

Here is the log output:

```
2017-06-19 17:18:34,961 Epoch[0] Train-rmse=0.500574
2017-06-19 17:18:34,961 Epoch[0] Time cost=0.007
2017-06-19 17:18:34,968 Epoch[0] Validation-rmse=0.500284
2017-06-19 17:18:34,975 Epoch[1] Train-rmse=0.500703
2017-06-19 17:18:34,975 Epoch[1] Time cost=0.007
2017-06-19 17:18:34,982 Epoch[1] Validation-rmse=0.500301
2017-06-19 17:18:34,990 Epoch[2] Train-rmse=0.500713
2017-06-19 17:18:34,990 Epoch[2] Time cost=0.008
2017-06-19 17:18:34,998 Epoch[2] Validation-rmse=0.500302
2017-06-19 17:18:35,005 Epoch[3] Train-rmse=0.500713
2017-06-19 17:18:35,005 Epoch[3] Time cost=0.007
2017-06-19 17:18:35,012 Epoch[3] Validation-rmse=0.500302
2017-06-19 17:18:35,019 Epoch[4] Train-rmse=0.500713
2017-06-19 17:18:35,019 Epoch[4] Time cost=0.007
2017-06-19 17:18:35,027 Epoch[4] Validation-rmse=0.500302
2017-06-19 17:18:35,035 Epoch[5] Train-rmse=0.500713
2017-06-19 17:18:35,035 Epoch[5] Time cost=0.008
2017-06-19 17:18:35,042 Epoch[5] Validation-rmse=0.500302
2017-06-19 17:18:35,049 Epoch[6] Train-rmse=0.500713
2017-06-19 17:18:35,049 Epoch[6] Time cost=0.007
2017-06-19 17:18:35,056 Epoch[6] Validation-rmse=0.500302
2017-06-19 17:18:35,064 Epoch[7] Train-rmse=0.500712
2017-06-19 17:18:35,064 Epoch[7] Time cost=0.008
2017-06-19 17:18:35,071 Epoch[7] Validation-rmse=0.500302
2017-06-19 17:18:35,079 Epoch[8] Train-rmse=0.500712
2017-06-19 17:18:35,079 Epoch[8] Time cost=0.007
2017-06-19 17:18:35,085 Epoch[8] Validation-rmse=0.500301
2017-06-19 17:18:35,093 Epoch[9] Train-rmse=0.500712
2017-06-19 17:18:35,093 Epoch[9] Time cost=0.007
2017-06-19 17:18:35,099 Epoch[9] Validation-rmse=0.500301
Classified as 0 with probability 0.530638
Classified as 0 with probability 0.530638
Classified as 0 with probability 0.530638
.
.
.
Classified as 0 with probability 0.530638
```

Can someone please clue me where I got wrong?

```
python version == 2.7.10
mxnet == 0.10.0
numpy==1.12.0
```

From the dataset I removed some non informative columns, and headers, and then converted it into csv format.

```
train_data.shape == (491, 22)
train_lbl.shape == (491,)
eval_data.shape == (452, 22)
eval_lbl.shape == (452,)
```

Comment: I uploaded the dataset used in this program [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f7d79gu4w9xgbdx/AABvKPiwN0axn4iVpOH4p_sya?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network definition seems right. Can you print the train_iter and val_iter to see if after normalisation the data is still what you expect? Also, what are the columns you are dropping from the original data?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @Naveen.
The train_iter and val_iter look okay, normally distributed. But with or without normalization code, they both yield poor result: no accuracy/rmse improvement. I dropped numbers of columns from the original data such as player names, but could you take a look at the files I uploaded? The link has the exact data which I am using in this program.